# Querying Field while Filtering Out Non-Numerical Characters - Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm at a crossroads in determining how I go about formatting a specific field.

A `document` identifier has changed how it is formatted and so I'm trying to find the best way (if there is even one) to query a database table.

Say I put in an array of newly formatted identifiers, but they were stored as the old way in the database.

I'd be inputting

```
31120313
31146631
31256061
```

but in the database, it currently looks like

```
3112031-3
3114663-1
3125606-1
```

I'm open to suggestions, as it is rather aggravating and I haven't come up with the need for something like this before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `Document` model, you can use there `where()` method for a record based on a value altered to replicate the previous identifier:

```
$value = substr_replace($str, '-', -1, 0);

Document::where('indentifier', $value)->first();
```

Here, we use `substr_replace` to insert a hyphen before the last character to find the record based on the old identifier.